# Restricting numeric input JavaScript problem

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to figure out why my JavaScript code is not restricting numeric input. Here's the code below:

```
(function(){
                if(window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener("load",init,false);
                else if(window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent("onload",init);
                
                function init() {
                    var keytest = document.getElementById("keytest");

                    function numericinput(event) {
                        var e = event || window.event;
                        var key = e.charcode || e.keyCode;  
                        var regex =/^\d+\.?\d{4}$/;
                        key = String.fromCharCode(key);     
                    
                        if (!regex.test(key)) {
                                alert("something");
                            
                            //if(e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
                            //if(e.returnValue) e.returnValue = false;
                            //return false;
                        }
                        else { //return true; 
                            alert("something else");
                         }                                      
                    }
                    
                    if(keytest.addEventListener) keytest.addEventListener("keypress",numericinput,false);
                    else {
                        keytest.onkeypress = numericinput();
                    }
                }
            })();
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `e.charcode` but it should be `e.charCode`

Your regexp is a bit off too, and you will need to deal with back-space etc.

You may as well just examine the keycode itself, [see](http://justins-fat-tire.blogspot.com/2007/09/javascript-numeric-only-text-box.html).